# using .where to test if an attribute is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I am using devise_invitable.

I am trying to find all users with `invitation_token != nil`

I thought that `User.where(:invitation_token != nil)`
will do.. but it returns all users..

when I do

```
pry(main)> User.where(:invitation_token != nil)[0].invitation_token
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ('t')
=> nil
```

so I don't understand what's going on here.. How do I find models using where when the test is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
User.where('invitation_token IS NOT NULL')
```

Your solution does not work, because `:invitation_token != nil` will evaluate to `true`, so what you actually did was:

```
User.where(true)
```

Comment: so I can't use a hash notation with :invitation_token and I must use a sql query?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid `IS NOT NULL` with the standard ActiveRecord Query Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your rails version, this is prettier:

```
User.where.not(invitation_token: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
User.where(:invitation_token => nil)
User.where("invitation_token IS NULL")
```

And it goes on...

Comment: but I want to find all users which their invitation_token is not nil